# Is the QGIS plugin repository broken?

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin, sextante

I'm connected to the QGIS plugins repository, using QGIS 1.8.0 on Windows 8.... and although I can see a total of 119 available plugins, I can't see Sextante anywhere in the browser.

I tried downloading the .zip file from https://github.com/jj0hns0n/sextante and unzipping it into the plugins directory, but then the browser just reports a "broken plugin"....

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with the Repository .xml. There are no entries listed in the repository browser (alphabetically) below Points2One

see Bug 7279
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7279

Hopefully it's fixed soon!